# Duda con funcionamiento funcion javascript dentro de modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Buen día,

Tengo una duda respecto de una función javascript que no me funciona dentro de un modal.

Tengo un formulario dentro de un modal que contiene varios campos a completar y algunos checkbox. De estos ultimo tengo uno que le incorporé una función javascript para que al presionarlo, desbloquee un campo para carga un archivo.

El código que les adjunto me funciona perfecto si el checkbox y input están fuera del modal, pero dentro no. (Perdón si está un poco desordenado, pero es un extracto del código completo)

```
<div class="form-group">                            
   <label for="eliminar_adjunto1">Eliminar Actual:</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="eliminar_adjunto1" id="eliminar_adjunto1" value="1" >  <!-- BOTON CHECK DEL ARCHIVO  -->
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">                  
    <label for="archivo1" class="tit">Adjuntar:</label>
    <input type="file" name="archivo1" id="archivo1" disabled>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 
   function toggleArchivoField() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('eliminar_adjunto1');
    var archivoField = document.getElementById('archivo1');
              
     if (checkbox.checked) {
        archivoField.removeAttribute('disabled');    
                              console.log('estado del checkbox:',checkbox.checked);
    } else {
        archivoField.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                              console.log('estado del checkbox:',checkbox.checked);
    }
 
}
document.getElementById('eliminar_adjunto1').addEventListener('change', toggleArchivoField);
 
</script>
```

Comment: Qué es lo que "no funciona" cuando está dentro de un modal? Acabo de poner tu código en un modal de bootstrap 5 y todo bien.

Comment: Al presionar el checkbox, no se habilita el input. Tengo la librería de bootstrap 4.3.1 será por eso?

Comment: Usa debugger y revisa si entra en tu condición o si ejecuta el método como tal

Comment: Cambié la función y en el debugger me muestra el funcionamiento de la función y el comportamiento del checkbox es correcto, pero aún así no se desbloquea el campo para cargar el archivo.

Comment: Puedes replicar el código con el problema en https://jsfiddle.net/  y postear el link? Más fácil revisar allí

Comment: Me resulta un poco complicado desde mi smartphone. Tendré que verlo más en la noche desde mi casa.

Comment: Probé tu código en un modal y funciona bien